# How to access USB device in chrome?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, applet

I need a web application which is used to copy the files from usb drive. I can write a java applet to copy the files from usb drive, but chrome will not support applet any more. Could you please suggest any alternative to this?
I need a web application not a chrome app.

Comment: Web apps don't have access to the file system. You can't copy files from a browser-bound application with the possible exception of browser extensions.

Comment: I can add a applet and it will give me permission to read and write from usb drive, but applet is no longer supported in chrome. so any alternative to it? Can I use webstart?

Comment: No, Web Start uses the same thing. In short, it's impossible to directly access the users machine from inside of Chrome anymore. You would need to have the user install an extension or some other external program.

Comment: As per the oracle, it still supports webstart. https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml. . This change does not affect Web Start applications, it only impacts applets. Is it not true?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 61+ has an [implementation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web) of the [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/)

This **would not** let you issue a command to the OS/File system to, for example:

copy `file://some_file_location/myfile.txt` to  `file://USB_DRIVE/some_folder/myfile.txt`

Chrome would need to read the files and write to the device directly. In other words the browser would be copying the files by *reading them* (see below) and then writing to the USB device. This would probably be quite slow and unfeasible for large files.

Your options to read local files are:

- To run chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag. This is a security issue/risk, and users would need to visit your site/application with this already on.
- Use the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), or the [non-standard FileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API#Browser_compatibility) APIs along with a `input type="file"` or drag & drop

Neither of these may be applicable to your problem/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using node.js , its cross platform and can access usb ports from web browser..

**Usb Library:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb

**Proof :** [How to send data to USB device in node.js using libusb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695614/how-to-send-data-to-usb-device-in-node-js-using-libusb)

Hope this helps

Comment: This would mean to run the node.js server on the computer of the user, which i guess is not what the OP want.

Comment: Yes, I will be running the web application on server.

Comment: Then this is a possible solution for you