# How do I send a signal from a USB port to a HTML website?

Tags: javascript, html, usb

I know that there is a javascript (maybe library?) that can handle this, but what is the syntax and how do I do this? Also, how do I code the usb to send the signal to the JS or HTML?

(sorry, but I am a noob at all things hardware, and I need this to work XD)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

Comment: What type of signal do you want to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `node-usb` for this https://github.com/tessel/node-usb, compare the docs to the USB basics in http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

in general for accessing a USB device the following steps have to be done :

- device
- configuration ( in node-usb only the default configuration is supported )
- claim interface
- access endpoints ( writing and reading  the actual data )

cf http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/ and other `libusb` tutorials

a general example for `node-usb` is in  [How to send data to USB device in node.js using libusb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695614/how-to-send-data-to-usb-device-in-node-js-using-libusb)

http://mikeheavers.com/tutorials/reading_data_from_usb_devices_using_javascript/

a more advanced example ( kinect control ) is in https://github.com/schakko/node-usb/blob/master/examples/kinect/kinect.js

( https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web )

Comment: THANKS! appreciated